# Safari doesnt save cookie data but IE/FF does?

Tags: javascript, browser, cookies, safari

I'm stuck with this weird issue in Safari. I'm storing a user selection data in a cookie using javascript.

I create the cookie using following code -

```
document.cookie = cookieName +
           "=" + encodeURIComponent(cookieValue) +
           "; expires=" + jsDate.toGMTString();
```

and its read using -

```
var cookie = document.cookie;
    if(cookie.length !== 0){
         var theCookie=" "+document.cookie;
         var ind=theCookie.indexOf(" "+cookieName+"=");
         if (ind==-1) ind=theCookie.indexOf(";"+cookieName+"=");
         if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
         var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind+1);
         if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
         return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+2,ind1));}
        else { return '';}
```

This code works fine in Firefox and IE but when I access this cookie's data in Safari - an empty string is returned. The weird thing is, if i REPEAT my selection and try again, i can access the data. In other words, the first time i access my site, the cookie data is unavailable but in subsequent attempts the data is available!

To see this issue again, i have to clear Safari's cache, history and delete the cookies from the "Show cookies" section and reopen the browser.

Another observation - when i fail to read the cookie data, we can see the cookie when we look under Safari > Preferences > Security > Show cookies

ps:
facing this with Safari version 4 & 5

Comment: also i tried iterating through all the cookies in document.cookie but that didn't show this cookie either (note - Only when i experience this issue)

Comment: Is this executed inside an `<iframe>` or something? Safari indeed disallows this. Other than that, Safari has a pretty restrictive cookie policy. Something in your code must have triggered its "possible attack!" alert.

Comment: aix, if you change the cookie value on subsequent requests, is this change reflected in `document.cookie` immediately? Just wondering if you are always looking at the cookies from the previous request... and it sounds like a Safari bug to which there will be solution but to refresh the page, but you never know

Comment: It doesn't sound like it, but any chance you are incorrectly setting expires the 1st time?

Comment: well its the same "createCookie()" function which gets called both the times + when i view the cookie details under "Show cookies" in Safari, the expires date is displayed correctly (its set to expire in 7 days)